# Improve Performance of SQL

Tags: oracle, query-performance

I have a requirement to get the data from table A which are not present in table B. Can anyone tell me which way would be more efficient in terms of run time out of all below queries.

```
select col1 from A 
minus
select col1 from B

select col1 from A where not exists (select 1 from B where A.col1=B.col1)

select X from (select A.col1 as "X" ,B.col1 as "Y" from A left outer join B on A.col1=B.col1) where Y is null
```

Comment: You can use "Explain plan" to determine this. According to it the last 2 queries have the same cost and are slightly faster than the first one. On the other hand, working with set operations (union, minus, intersect) is considered faster...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any question of the form "what is the most efficient way to write a SQL statement that does X" the answer is always the same-- it depends.

The cost-based optimizer (CBO) takes into account a huge variety of statistics about the data in the tables involved in order to decide what plan to use.  Depending on your data, it is entirely possible that the three queries would produce the same query plan (and would thus have identical performance).  It is also possible that you'd get three different plans.  If you get different plans, you'd need to see which plan was most efficient for your objects and your data on your hardware.  Of course, as your data changes, the CBO is free to come up with different (hopefully better) plans for your SQL statements so the "best" plan is a moving target.  The plan that may be most efficient today may not be most efficient tomorrow.

Given that, my bias is always to start with the query that most clearly expresses the logic I am trying to implement.  Write the most readable SQL you can and let the optimizer come up with the plan.  If a particular query turns out to be a bottleneck and you need to optimize it, one of the options is to rewrite the query (Oracle has many other ways to influence query plans if the optimizer happens to choose a less efficient plan that don't require rewriting the query).  To me, the `MINUS` and the `EXISTS` are both relatively clear ways to write the SQL statement so I wouldn't object to either.  The `LEFT JOIN`, on the other hand, strikes me as much less clear-- you're intentionally asking for data in an inner query then filtering it out at another layer-- so I would not recommend using that approach without strong evidence that it is actually more efficient in your environment.